# Is there any javascript listener for an addition of an element into another element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I think everything is in the title.

Is there any way to add a listener into an dom element triggered when any oher element is append into.

```
jQuery("#rootElement").bind("addElementEvent", function() {
    console.log("Element was added");
});

<div id="rootElement"></div>
```

And when smth like that :

```
jQuery("#rootElement").append("<div >another element</div>");
```

Trigger:

```
Element was added
```

I don't know if I'm really clear ...

Comment: The best you can realistically do is an access-control abstraction (think getters/setters). That will only work for nodes **you** insert, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called, "Mutation Events". Those events are available in all modern browsers, but non-the-less they are flagged as obsolete for quite a while now.

For instance

```
jQuery("#rootElement").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function( e ) {
    console.log("Element was added");
});
```

jsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P6wdH/

Reference: [MDN DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference)

As I already mentioned, this works in almost all modern browsers. But its still some sort of a risk to use them. Since there is no alternative in any spec yet, I don't think those events will be gone soon, but you should be aware of the current state.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin called [livequery()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) that does exactly what you need ... example usage :

```
$('#idofelement').livequery(function() {
   // perform selector on $(this) to apply class   
});
```

Using this would perform the function when the DOM element with the id `idofelement` was added

Comment: As long as jQuery is being used to do the append.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php there is an event called `DOMNodeInserted` supported by major browsers. But I don't know about older version of IE